# Getting TypeError when setting spreasheet column value

Tags: python

```
for product_row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2,
                                       max_row=worksheet.max_row,
                                       min_col=1,
                                       max_col=5, values_only=True):
    test_write = worksheet.cell(product_row,5)
    test_write.value = 5
```

Gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProject\main.py", line 62, in <module>
    test_write = worksheet.cell(product_row,5)
  File "C:\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 237, in cell
    if row < 1 or column < 1:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

*But* when I have this:

```
for product_row in range(2, worksheet.max_row+1):
    test_write = worksheet.cell(product_row,5)
    test_write.value = 5
```

I do not get any error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `iter_rows` return?

Comment: I checked [the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=iter_rows#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) and `iter_rows` yields cells, so you don't have to call `worksheet.cell`, you've already got the cell.

Comment: Thanks Peter Wood. iter_rows() returns a row and I can access each cell by row[0], row[1] and so on. There 4 columns and I want to add value in the cell of the fifth column of each row.